# Google Calender API:SSL connection error

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp, google-calendar-api

I am trying to execute a sample Google Calender API [Application](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/calendar/simple.php) in my local machine using XAMPP .

I am able to run this application but after the step where user authenticates using my application . It throw's me "SSL connection error" .

I tried enabling php_openssl.dll any many other things . But nothing works .

I am using Google Crome Browser .

This is url where i run my application

```
http://localhost:81/google-api-php-client/examples/calendar/simple.php
```

Since Apace is running on port 81.